# Не понятная ошибка при ответе с сервере, вместо Json возвращается это

Tags: json, swift

```
class SignUp: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var buttonNameTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonEmailTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonPwdTxt: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func buttonSignIn(_ sender: UIButton){

let usermainname:NSString = buttonNameTxt.text! as NSString
let username:NSString = buttonEmailTxt.text! as NSString
let password:NSString = buttonPwdTxt.text! as NSString


let myURL = NSURL(string: "https:\\mev.com/api/login") //(адресс изменен, т.к. проект для работы) 
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL as! URL)
request.httpMethod = "Post"


let postString = "name = \(usermainname) email = \(username) &passwod = \(password) "
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
data , response , error in

do {

let err: NSError?
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

print(json as Any)

if let parseJSON = json {
let resultValue = parseJSON["status"] as? String
print ("result:\(resultValue)")

var isUserRegister:Bool = false
if resultValue == "success" {isUserRegister = true}

var messageToDisplay:String = parseJSON["massage"] as! String
if isUserRegister {

messageToDisplay = parseJSON["massage"] as! String

}


}


} catch {

print("error")
}
```

а вот ошибка

```
2016-11-16 12:37:16.328505 MevicsPromo[12011:692688] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/HardBuf/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3B4C6A4-A49D-4363-89D5-31931EA513A8/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-11-16 12:37:16.328782 MevicsPromo[12011:692688] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2016-11-16 12:37:18.276331 MevicsPromo[12011:692798] 0x60000014e4f0 Copy matching assets reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY <dictionary: 0x60000014e4f0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"Result" => <int64: 0x61000002c100>: 29
}
2016-11-16 12:37:18.277030 MevicsPromo[12011:692798] 0x608000357b80 Daemon configuration query reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY <dictionary: 0x608000357b80> { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"Dictionary" => <dictionary: 0x6080003576b0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"ServerURL" => <dictionary: 0x608000357290> { count = 3, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
"com.apple.CFURL.magic" => <uuid: 0x608000052060> C3853DCC-9776-4114-B6C1-FD9F51944A6D
"com.apple.CFURL.string" => <string: 0x608000059d40> { length = 30, contents = "https:\\mesu.apple.com/assets/" }
"com.apple.CFURL.base" => <null: 0x10a307f20>: null-object
}
}
"Result" => <int64: 0x608000229a20>: 0
}
2016-11-16 12:37:18.277318 MevicsPromo[12011:692798] http:\\ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help[MobileAssetError:29] Unable to copy asset information from https:\\mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.TextInput.SpellChecker
```

Comment: `https:\\mev.com/api/login` <- эм-м, обратные слэши?

Comment: Специально изменил, т.к. это первый вопрос здесь, не пускал с ссылками

Comment: чего то не могу там ошибку разглядеть. можно все активити логи убрать

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: И самое главное, я не регестрируюсь по адресу, тоесть данные вроде как отправляются но на стороне сервера пусто(

Comment: ну вы говорите вот ошибка. а я там слова error нигде не вижу. может точнее указать